# Firestore Rules - dynamic path

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a dynamic connection in Firestore's Rules.

I have a users collections and a roles collections, each user in the users collection has a 'string' field which matches the firebase generated ID for the corresponding role in the roles collection.

In order to achieve this I am trying to dynamically get the ID and then retrieve the appropriate data from the role.

My code is as follows:

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{collections}/{collection=**} {
        function getRole() {
            return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role;
        }

        function getPermissions(role) {
            return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/roles/$(role)).data.test;
        }

        allow read: if true;

        // Role equals to 12345
        // allow write: if getRole() == 12345; <-- THIS WORKS
        // allow write: if getPermissions(12345) == true; <-- THIS WORKS
        // Need to put dynamic getRole() which equals to 12345 inside of getPermissions() 
        // instead of the static 12345

        // THIS DOES NOT WORK           
        allow write: if getPermissions(getRole()) == true;
    }
}}
```

A potential reason why this is not working is that the get() functions are asynchronous and do not wait for the previous one to finish hence why it can't use its data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Open to workarounds, data structure changes, etc...

Answer (score 0):

did tests on your example and it works for me

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {

        function getRole() {
            return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/test-user/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role;
        }

        function getPermissions(role) {
            return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/test-role/$(role)).data.rights;
        }

        match /test-user/{userid} {
            allow read: if true; 
            allow write: if getPermissions(getRole()) == 'all';
        }
    }
}
```

Content of my test set is

```
/test-user/0fludECgWKg88Gn5SjNYPc3Opmx2 (id of my test user) has: 
    {"role": "tr"}

/test-role/tr has: 
    {"rights": "all"}
```

If `/test-role/tr` doesn't exist or `rights` doesn't have value `all`, write request is rejected

In your case, maybe just the type of the function `getPermissions` is string and the test expects a boolean.